# Unable to draw paddles for pong game

Tags: javascript

Okay, I've been converting my "function spaghetti" into revealing prototypes for my Pong game, and haven't had any luck drawing the paddles.

This will draw a black canvas, but the paddles refuse to draw.

I commented out the clearCanvas() to see if it was an issue there, but to no avail.

Seems like you'll definitely want to http://jsbeautifier.org the code below, as it didn't transfer very well =c

```
/*jslint browser: true, devel: true, indent: 4, undef: true, todo: true*/

canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = 600;
canvas.height = 400;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
context = canvas.getContext('2d');

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var Paddle = function (playerSide) {
'use strict';
//constructor, variables go here
var x, y = 20,
    width = 10, height = 50,
    colour = '#FFF';
//Determine which paddle belongs to which player
if (playerSide === 'left') {
    this.x = 20;
} else {
    this.x = 580;
}
};

Paddle.prototype = function () {
"use strict";
//Private members
var draw = function (x, y) {
    context.fillStyle = this.colour;
    context.fillRect(x, y, this.width, this.height);
};
//Public members
return {
    draw: draw
};
}();

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var Pong = function () {
"use strict";
//constructor, variables go here
//Events
canvas.onmousemove = function (mouse) {
    this.y = mouse.pageY;
};
this.animate();
};

Pong.prototype = (function () {
"use strict";
//Private members
// requestAnim shim layer by Paul Irish
window.requestAnimFrame = (function () {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
        function (/* function */callback, /* DOMElement */element) {
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
}());

var animate = function () {
        requestAnimFrame(animate);
        clearCanvas();
        drawPaddles();
    },

    drawPaddles = function () {
        leftPaddle.draw(leftPaddle.x, leftPaddle.y);
        rightPaddle.draw(rightPaddle.x, rightPaddle.y);
    },

    clearCanvas = function () {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 400);
    };

//Public members
return {
    animate: animate
};
}());

var leftPaddle = new Paddle('left');
var rightPaddle = new Paddle('right');

var pong = new Pong();
```

​

Any ideas what's going on, or what concept I'm not understanding?
Also, any comments about my code otherwise would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

EDIT: I initially initialized the paddles from the Pong class, I'm assuming that's correct, but this code has undergone so many changes as I was trying to fix the paddle issue... arrrg!

Comment: remember `fillStyle = 'White';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be with your 'private members', colour, width and height. These members are in the closure of some privileged member functions - and that means they can't be accessed as properties of 'this'.

For instance, in the following code

```
function myClass() {
    var x = 1;
    this.sayX = function() {return this.x};
    var y = 2;
    this.sayY = function() {return y};
}

var myObject = new myClass();

myObject.sayX(); // returns 'undefined'
myObject.sayY(); // returns '2'
```

You need to either remove your references to 'this' in your methods that call the pseudo-private members and define the functions that call them in the same context, or make them public members of the object. Otherwise the draw functions won't have access to the colour and dimensions of the paddles (which explains why they don't draw).

Comment: I tried removing the 'this' references in my draw method, but the paddles are still not being drawn, and I receive "Uncaught ReferenceError: colour is not defined". What did I screw up?

Comment: Also, when I remove those references completely, and add in the values directly, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Nevermind, it was the x and y, now I need to figure that out =b

Comment: hmm, not only the x and y, it's all 4 of the values I'm screwing up here "context.fillRect(x, y, this.width, this.height);" =/

Comment: @user1156929 - I'm confused as to what's not working. There are five variables to pass to the draw function - which one is OK, and what's going wrong with the other four? Are you getting exceptions in the console?

Comment: Okay, I think I figured it out, when I'm initializing the variables in 
"var Paddle = function", I need to use this.width and this.height instead of var width= and height=

Comment: var Paddle = function (playerSide) {
    'use strict';
    //constructor, variables go here
    this.x, this.y = 20,
        this.width = 10, this.height = 50,
        this.colour = '#FFF';

This is what I did, and it fixed the issue of the paddles drawing, now I need to figure out why they aren't following my mouse =b

Comment: @user1156929 - you *can* keep the variables private, but you must define the draw function in the same context as the private vars. They're not private members, they're just the closure of the returned functions.

Comment: You've done a lot already and I appreciate it, but this seems to be a tad over my head. Would you be able to show me the correct object code for the Paddle on JSFiddle, so I can look at the code and review your changes? Much appreciated! EDIT: Not for the mouse movement, I'll figure that out afterwards.

Comment: Figured out the mouse FWIW, did leftPaddle.y instead of this.y (which makes sense now that I look back at it), able to tell via the console that it's working.

Comment: I got it! I changed the all the fillRect parameters with leftPaddle.x, leftPaddle.y, leftPaddle.width, and leftPaddle.height, and now it draws, and moves it correctly. Is there a correct way I can reference "this instance" of paddle, instead of hard-coding the "leftPaddle." and "rightPaddle."?

Comment: @user1156929 - I think you might benefit from reading some more documentation on javascript. Find out about objects, scope and functions in particular. A good source is Nicholas Zakas' "Professional Javascript for Web Developers", or anything by Douglas Crockford. They're not for newbies, but they're very unambiguous and extremely comprehensive.

Comment: In case anyone sees this in the future, I moved the variables into the .prototype, and was able to access them that way.